# How to sort double array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, double

I got an double array declared was followed:

```
double myArray[4] = {0.0, 5.0, 2.1, 99.1};
```

But I got no idea how I can sort this array like (min - max) or the other direction.
All that I found during my research was code, how to sort vectors.

> So my question. How to apply a sort routine on this array the right way?

```
double myArray[4] = {0.0, 5.0, 2.1, 99.1};

std::sort(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), [](const double& a, const double& b) {
                return a > b;
            }); // not working this way
```

Comment: Hint: `std::begin`/`std::end`.

Comment: for non-compiling code, please include the error message in the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
std::sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), comparator);
```

[`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) are free functions that, by default, just return `x.begin()`/`x.end()`, respectively, thus they work with standard containers - `std::list`, `std::vector`, `std::array`, etc. These functions are also specialized for plain old C arrays, enabling the aforementioned code.

You could also throw pointers directly into `std::sort`, since pointers are iterators:

```
std::sort(myArray, myArray + 4, comparator);
```

However, this requires you to specify the size of the array (which can be done automatically, though), and breaks as soon as you change `myArray` to be, say, an `std::vector`.

Note that `std::sort` uses [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) if you don't specify the comparator, meaning that it sorts in ascending order by default. If you need descending order, you can specify [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) instead:

```
std::sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), std::greater<double>{});
```

Comment: You can also use default comparators such as: `std::less<double>()` and `std::greater<double>()`  depending on which kind of sorting you want.

Comment: @woz That's true. It is not so useful in case of `std::less`, since that's what `std::sort` uses by default. I'll add this to the answer, thank you.

Comment: you're right! I just mentioned `std::less` in case OP didn't know the default behavior. I actually believe that the whole reference for `greater`, `less`, and their "friends" should be known, hence: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/ - starting with greater, OP can explore all other options :)

Comment: It's worth noting that `std::sort` uses `operator<` by default, which has fewer guarantees than `std::less` for pointer types (`std::less` is guaranteed to yield a total order for pointer types while `operator<` on pointers only yields a partial order).